# For an ActiveRecord model with overridden `New` method, how to provide custom test subject with parameters using FactoryGirl in Rails shoulda matchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, factory-bot, shoulda-matchers

I have an Rails `ActiveRecord` model which has the `new` method overridden. The `new` method accepts a parameter and instantiates an object of this model, with other required fields.

In RSpec Model specs with Shoulda matchers, I'm testing associations.

How can I pass a custom test subject using FactoryGirl?

The Model is:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :folders, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
end
```

The Model spec is:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Document do
   describe 'associations' do
    it { should have_many(:folders).dependent(:destroy) }
    it { should belong_to(:project) }
    it { should belong_to(:author).class_name('User') }
  end
end
```

#### Stack Details

- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- Rails 5.2.2
- Rspec 3.8.0
- Shoulda-matchers 3.1.3
- FactoryGirl 4.9.0

As a workaround, I've set the test subject to an instance of the `Document` class, with the parameters passed to the overridden `new` method.

This works but, doesn't use the defined factories of FactoryGirl.

I'm expecting to use FactoryGirl and provide custom parameters to the test subject using the defined factory.

Comment: You can access the parameters of a factory with `attributes_for :factory_name`.

Comment: `new` is not just an ActiveRecord method but a Ruby method. I try to not give answers which tell people that their approach is wrong, but in this case I have to go with "don't override new".

Comment: @Archonic - I do know about `new`. Yes, I agree about avoiding to override new. It's just legacy code that I can't update for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `initialize_with` and modify the document factory as follows:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :document do
    project
    author factory: :user
    # other attributes for document

    initialize_with { new(custom_arg_value) } # replace custom_arg_value with your value
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @piowit, I was able to solve this using `transient {...}` and `initialize_with {...}`.